# Mercon LV for CVT transmissions

Tags: transmission

I have a 2008 Subaru Outback limited with a CVT transmission. Can Mercon LV be safely used in place of Dexron VI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  See [this chart](https://whlubricants.com/files/products/p1egqirde01ocvfafr2l18nv2kl5_0.pdf) for reference.

If you are willing to consider an upgrade to OEM fluid, I'd suggest [Lube Gard COMPLETE™ Full Synthetic ATF](https://www.lubegard.com/products/atf/#section3).  I used this fluid in my Mercedes, with noticeably better shifting.  It lasts much longer than OEM fluids.